# How to actualize a text

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know how i can actualize a text using JavaScript, like:

- I have a variable named `add`
- for each click on a button named "click", i want to write hello and the number with corresponds to `add`

If `add` = 5, when i click i want to have:  `hello, 5`

and if i click again i want to have `hello, 10`, but and not:

```
hello, 5  
10
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We would be happy to help, but the rules are that you do have to attempt the problem beforehand. Do you happen to have code for us to work with?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

by coincidence I had a similar code in a lost notepad (kkk), I just made an adaptation for you:
HTML:

```
<div >
    <button type="button" onclick="incrementNumber()">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="content">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var number = 0;
var increment = 5;
var keyWord = "hello, ";
//you mention that you need a text var
var text = "";
function incrementNumber(){
        number += increment;
        text = keyWord + number;
        //just for show;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set `add` to the value to increment by
Set `current` to 0
Set `target` to the add button
Add an event listener to `target` of type 'click' with callback function:
    Set `current` to sum of `current` and `add`
    Log `'Hello, ' + current`
```

```js
var add = 5;
var current = 0;
var target = document.getElementById('target');
target.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    current = current + add;
    console.log('Hello, ' + current);
});
```

```html
<button id="target">Add</button>
```